# Is there a nice(r) Taylor expansion of the normal quantile function?

Tags: normal-distribution, probit, taylor-series

Letting $\Phi$ be the CDF of the standard normal, and $\Phi^{-1}$ be the quantile function of the normal, I am looking for the Taylor series expansion of
$$
\Phi^{-1}\left(\Phi\left(x\right) + \epsilon\right).
$$
Using the Taylor series expansion of the inverse error function, I believe I get something like
$$
\Phi^{-1}\left(\Phi\left(x\right) + \epsilon\right) = 
x + \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[2\epsilon + \frac{\pi}{12}\left(3\left(2\Phi\left(x\right)-1\right)^2 2\epsilon
+ 3\left(2\Phi\left(x\right)-1\right) 4\epsilon^2 + 8\epsilon^3\right) + \ldots \right].
$$
This is a bit ugly for my tastes, and would prefer to collect the terms in powers of $\epsilon$. Is this a known expansion?

(FWIW, I am getting the $\epsilon$ from the Edgeworth expansion.)

Comment: I think maybe I should just use a Cornish-Fisher expansion instead...